# MS Access: How would I update a value in a table to the sum of said value and the value from a query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

If I have the table `tblValues` with the following records

```
RecordMonth(PK)   |   TotalRecords   |   TotalVariances
Jan               |   15             |   2
Feb               |   10             |   1
Mar               |   8              |   0
.                 |                  |
.                 |                  |
.                 |                  |
Dec               |   11             |   1
```

and the query `qryDailyValues` with the following records calculated from a separate temporary table that is deleted and repopulated each day when we perform an item count

```
RecordMonth   |   CountOfTodaysRecords   |   CountOfTodaysVariances
Feb           |   2                      |   1
```

How would I go about updating the appropriate `tblValues`record (in this case `Feb` since that is when the count took place) with the sum of `qryDailyValues.CountOfTodaysRecords` and `tblValues.TotalRecords`? End result being the `Feb` record's `TotalRecords` set to 12 (10+2) and `TotalVariances` set to 2 (1+1).

Every time I try and create an update query to update Field: `TotalRecords` from Table: `tblValues` and Update To: `=TotalRecords + qryDailyValues.CountOfTodaysRecords`, it just prompts me for the `qryDailyValues.CountOfTodaysRecords` parameter instead of just pulling it from the query. Same goes for updating `TotalVariances` with itself plus `CountOfTodaysVariances`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I realized I made two mistakes that prevented me my update query from working.

First, my select query (`qryDailyValues`) was not "updateable" due to it containing aggregate functions. I resolved this by turning it into a make table query, allowing it to create a temporary table, that is then deleted and remade every time it is ran.

Second, my update query needed to have the destination table joined to the new temporary source table (created by the make table query) on the related field, `RecordMonth`.

After all of this was setup properly, the update query properly pulled values from the temporary source table, and added them to the existing values of the destination table.